# Неправильно отправляется json ответ

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, почему у меня неправильно отправляется json ответ. Вот код в js файле:

```
$('#test_form').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var obj = {
                            'id': 1
                        };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://geo/points.php",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: 'obj='+JSON.stringify(obj),
                            success: function(msg){
                                $("#result").empty();
                                $("#result").append(msg['long_st']);
                                console.log(msg['long_st']);
                            },
                            error: function(msg) { //Если ошибка
                                console.log(msg['long_st']);
                            }
                        });});
```

Код из php файла:

```
if ($_POST['obj']){
include_once("db/config.php");
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM delivery");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
json_encode($row);
exit();}
```

В js ответ приходит с ошибкой (этим блоком

```
error: function(msg) { //Если ошибка
                                console.log(msg['long_st']);
                            }
```

Я проверял и `console.log(msg['long_st'])` в консоле пишет: `undefined`. Никак немогу понять почему.

Comment: echo json_encode( array( "html1" => $html1, "html2" => $html2 ) );

Answer (score 1):

Потому что:

а. никакого json не возвращается;
 б. `json_encode($row);` -> `echo json_encode($row);`
 в. `console.log(msg['long_st']);` -> никто не гарантирует, что при ошибке в msg будут какие-то ключи.

Comment: спасибо, заработало, но как сделать, чтобы отправляло не одну запись с таблицы в БД, а все что там есть? Еще такой вопрос: можно ли отправлять 2 разных ajax ответа с разных php файлов в один js скрипт?